# Errors for using HPPLE Html parser

Tags: objective-c, html-parser

i am trying to use HPPLE parser but i get these errors! anyone can help me for example why NASData cant has error ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your code inside of some function. If you are making a command-line tool this would usually be `main()`. Otherwise you'll have to set up an interface, application delegate, etc.

Comment: @saleh If it was helpful, you should consider accepting it as the answer.

Comment: @Deepak It may have been too early to accept, but yes, thanks :)